# Extracting out a string given a starting and ending pattern using MySQL/Presto

Tags: mysql, hive, presto

Trying to extract text out of a string given a certain starting and ending pattern.

Don't really know where to start. I've looked around and tried to make sense out of regex functions but they go over my head.

Table:

```
+----+------------------------------------+
| id |              sentence              |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  1 | Hello, I am a bird.                |
|  2 | Hello, I am a cat. I like catfood. |
|  3 | Hello, I am a dog. I like bones.   |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

Trying to extract the text between `Hello,`  and `.`

Output:

```
+-------------+
|  sentence   |
+-------------+
| I am a bird |
| I am a cat  |
| I am a dog  |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [**`regexp_extract(col,regexp,capture_group)`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function in hive:

```
Hello,    //match "Hello," literal
([^.]*)  //then until first occurrence of .(period) capture as first group
```

***Example:***

```
hive> select regexp_extract(sentence,"Hello,([^.]*)",1)sentence from( 
          --preparing sample data
           select stack(3,'Hello, I am a bird.','Hello, I am a cat. I like catfood.','Hello, I am a dog. I like bones.')
              as(sentence))t;
```

***Result:***

```
sentence
 I am a bird
 I am a cat
 I am a dog
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you.